# Does running apt-get update/upgrade require a nginx reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Each time or often enough when I run apt-get update then upgrade, I get a nginx 502 error.  Rebooting the server brings everything back up.

I'm guessing I have to restart nginx each time?

BTW, how can I figure out where my nginx is installed so I can call reboot on it?

its been a while since I terminalled into this test vps (still learning)

Comment: Do you see the 502 from the apt-get command?  I'm guessing the problem is apt-get is configured to use a mirror that you do not have permission to access.

Comment: Add output of apt command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what `/etc/init.d/nginx` in Ubuntu does, but I can explain what mechanisms Nginx has so that you can upgrade it without interrupting service.

If you'd install/upgrade Nginx from the sources, you'd certainly build it at the first. Then you issue `make install` to copy new binary.

Then, you have to learn what is PID of Nginx "master" process:

```
ps ax | grep nginx
```

and find "master" process PID in the output. Let's assume it's 123.

Then send `USR2` signal to the master process:

```
kill -USR2 123
```

You can review Nginx's `error.log` and the list of processses (`ps ax | grep nginx`) to make sure that a new instance of Nginx has started.

Issue `WINCH` signal:

```
kill -WINCH 123
```

Now the new Nginx instance will get requests. And the old worker processes shutdown gracefully. Again, review `error.log` to make sure everything goes fine.

And finally,

```
kill -QUIT 123
```

will shutdown old Nginx master. After that, your system has new Nginx installed and running.

This procedure ensures all the connections are served without interruptions.